# ColdFusion report template appears to be malformed or contains errors.

Tags: coldfusion, report

I am using ColdFusion 2016 and ColdFusion 10 Report Builder to generate .cfr reports

when I call a report using the tag **CFREPORT**

```
<cfreport template="reportName.cfr" filename="uploadedfiles\myReport.xls" format="xls">  
     <cfreportparam name="EmpNo" value="20002">  
</cfreport>
```

sometimes I get the error

```
report "Name of report" template appears to be malformed or contains errors.
```

I have to restart the ColdFusion Service in order to get rid of this error, and the report will work again without any problem,
The problem is that restarting the service on the prod environment is not an easy option... any recommendation please ?

Comment: Is there a stack trace to go along with the error?  Look in your ColdFusion log files.

Comment: We're running into the "Malformed or contains errors" issue now; did you ever resolve this? We're wondering if it has anything to do with the default output type being "flashpaper."